# Changing input to link how to do that?

Tags: php, html, forms, hyperlink, rename

I need a code that when i get `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ktvTqknDobU` That the php script rename it to `http://bloxhotel.nl/video?watch=ktvTqknDobU`

And after done that load that page.

Sorry for my bad english.

I have tried this

```
<form action="welcome_get.php" method="get">
Youtube Link: <input type="text" name="link"><br>

<input type="submit">
</form>
```

and this

```
<?php
ob_start();
include 'includes/inc.bootstrap.php';
$page = Array(
    'title' => ((isset($user)) ? $user->username : ''),
    'onload' => ((isset($_GET['utm_source']) && $_GET['utm_source'] == 'welcome') ? 'Pixel.View.OpenUrlOverlay(\'/pixlett/Video.php\');' : ''),
    'tab' => Array('me', 'home'), 'access' => Array(true, false)
);
include 'content/header.php';
include 'content/menu.php';
?>

<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['link']); ?>
```

Comment: The page also need to reload to that link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`str_replace()`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_replace.asp) function

```
$youtube = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ktvTqknDobU";
$link = str_replace("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=","http://bloxhotel.nl/video?watch=",$youtube);
```

Use `<a href>` for link.

```
echo "<a href='$link'>Video Link</a>";
```

Comment: @MikeSant check the answer, When you click on Video Link it will redirect you to the page

Answer (score 0):

You can use str_replace() php inbuilt function,

```
 $link =  "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ktvTqknDobU";

 $match =  "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=";

 $tobeReplaced = "http://bloxhotel.nl/video?watch=";

 echo $RequiredLink = str_replace($match, $tobeReplaced, $link);
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php